# Блокировка действий пользователя JS

Tags: функции, javascript

Есть функция, которая вызывается onclick.
Длительность её выполнения - 1 секунда.
Как сделать так, чтобы на эту 1 секунду браузер не реагировал на действия пользователя, функция не вызывалась по 200 раз и т.д?

Comment: Так вам чтобы не реагировал весь браузер (я бы не стал этого делать)? Или чтобы конкретно эта функция не срабатывала? Ставьте флаг в род. области видимости, по окончании (анимации?) флаг снимайте. Если непонятно накидайте минипример на jsfiddle.

Comment: да, функция не срабатывала.
Там просто анимация и кликом и скролом, нужно отменить действие повторное воспроизведени функции во время проигрывания.

Comment: ну тогда так и сделайте как я сказал.http://plnkr.co/edit/VpDXzzjPjh4TEmCXkqSF?p=preview